# Joomla notify user by email about new article

Tags: joomla, categories, notify

I'm searching for compononent/plugin/other solution to notify selected users by email (i.e User Group) when I post new article into category, something like newsletter maybe but cannot find the good one. Any suggestions?

Comment: you mean automatically send email on new article or manually sending it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fellow Joomla user and have a good amount of experience with it.

I just did a quick search, and I think "JMailAlerts" might be a good option. While I'm not sure if it will instantly send users a category update, it uses Cron-Jobs to automatically send email updates either daily, weekly or monthly. Also, users can select which updates they want to receive.

**See here:** http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/marketing/mailing-a-distribution-lists/j-mailalerts

Hopefully that helps. I personally haven't used this extension because I haven't needed to do what you're looking for. But it's worth a test! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

[AcyMailing Business/Enterprise](https://www.acyba.com/acymailing/business.html) does exactly that but with the paid version of the extension. This can be achieved with the [Auto-Newsletter](http://www.acyba.com/acymailing/140-acymailing-autonewsletter.html) plugin.

See also this [discussion](https://www.acyba.com/forum/5-acymailing-how-to/28253-auto-email-whenever-new-joomla-article-published.html)

Answer (score 0):

Both of them uses cron-like methods and I want something what works instantly.